# Log response without sensitive data in .NET 5.0

Tags: c#, .net, api

I want to log (with ex Serilog) the response AND request from every endpoint in a .NET 5-API leaving out or sensoring data marked as sensitive. So far I tried to implement it with attributes in the data-class and logging from either filters or a middleware, but I haven't found a way to read property attributes. Does anyone have an example of how to do it?

```
public class Document {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [SensitiveData]
    public string NationalId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}

public class SensitiveDataAttribute : Attribute { }
```

Comment: How about serialize it as JSON and use the [`Ignore`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-ignore-properties?pivots=dotnet-5-0)-attribute?

Comment: That could be an option, wasn't aware of it.

Comment: Let me know if you still need an answer and I'll try to wrap something up.

Answer (score 0):

I took inspiration from [smoksnes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4949005/smoksnes) about using JsonIgnore as a attribute to hide properties from the data class:

```
public class Document
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string NationalId { get; set; }
    public byte[] Data { get; set; }
}
```

Then I added a filter which logged the request and response:

```
public class AsyncEndpointLogger : IAsyncResultFilter, IAsyncActionFilter
{
    private readonly ILogger<AsyncEndpointLogger> logger;

    public AsyncEndpointLogger(ILogger<AsyncEndpointLogger> logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task OnActionExecutionAsync(ActionExecutingContext context, ActionExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        context.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("body", out object request);
        logger.LogInformation("Request: " + JsonSerializer.Serialize(request));

        await next();
    }

    public async Task OnResultExecutionAsync(ResultExecutingContext context, ResultExecutionDelegate next)
    {
        var result = context.Result;
        if (result is ObjectResult response)
        {
            logger.LogInformation("Response: " + JsonSerializer.Serialize(response.Value));
        }

        await next();
    }
}
```

Added the filter in the controller through an attribute like:

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(AsyncEndpointLogger))]
[ApiController]
public class DocumentsController : ControllerBase
{
    public DocumentsController() { }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult<Document> CreateDocument([FromBody] Document body)
    {
        // Logic for adding document...

        return Ok(body);
    }
}
```

And registered it as a service in StartUp.ConfigureServices:

```
services.AddScoped<AsyncEndpointLogger>();
```

I appreciate comments on improvements or alternatives here.